# Move items from one QListWidget to another

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlistwidget

I have to QListWidgets, one source list, one destiny list and one button. Whenever the button is clicked, I want the selected item(s) from the source list to be removed and inserted into the destiny list. I tried to `source_list.removeWidgetItem(aSelectedItem)` but that does not even do a thing. :( What am I doing wrong? Do I need to update the list afterwards somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`takeItem` will take the item from the source_list and give you a pointer to it you can use to append it to your destination list.  Something like:

```
source_list = new QListWidget();
dest_list = new QListWidget();
new QListWidgetItem(tr("Oak"), source_list);
new QListWidgetItem(tr("Birch"), source_list);
connect(source_list, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(swapEntry(QModelIndex)));


void MyWidget::swapEntry(QModelIndex index)
{
    dest_list->insertItem(dest_list->count(), source_list->takeItem(index.row()));
}
```